# Toggle checkbox if displayed in table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, checkbox

I have a table with some `rows and columns`. And there is an image which is representing a `checkbox in each row and column`. Basically upon clicking on the image, it would select that check box (image selector).

What I wanted to do is when I click on one image(checkbox), the rest becomes hidden and clicking it again would show the rest (toggle).

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.sign-reason').change(function() {
    $(this).parent('td').siblings().toggle();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <label>
          <input name="sign-reason" type="checkbox" value="damaged" class="sign-reason">
          <img src="../../css/signs/cantilever.png" class="sign_selector" rel="{cantilever}">
        <label></label>
        </label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <label>
          <input name="sign-reason" type="checkbox" value="damaged" class="sign-reason">
          <img src="../../css/signs/950x300.png" class="sign_selector" rel="{950x300}">
          <label></label>
        </label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <label>
          <input name="sign-reason" type="checkbox" value="damaged" class="sign-reason">
          <img src="../../css/signs/1300x370.png" class="sign_selector" rel="{1300x370}">
          <label></label>
        </label>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
        <label>
          <input name="sign-reason" type="checkbox" value="damaged" class="sign-reason">
          <img src="../../css/signs/1000x300freestanding.png" class="sign_selector" rel="{1000x300fs}">
          <label></label>
        </label>
      </td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>
        <label>
          <input name="sign-reason" type="checkbox" value="damaged" class="sign-reason">
          <img src="../../css/signs/1100x300.png" class="sign_selector" rel="{1100x300}">
          <label></label>
        </label>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Is it possible when I click on `image`, all other `images` become hidden and clicking again would show the images.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery's show() and hide() methods. But we had some strange outputs when we used them(it does not occur always), instead for hiding them we changed the html attribute "display: none" and toggled back in with show(). Of course after controlling if the image is checked or not.

You can create functions accordingly under your button click function according to what you want to hide or show, and you can implement the toggle. Goodluck !

Answer (score 0):

Better you can create a CSS style to hide the element and toggle the class .

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {

    $('.sign-reason').change(function() {
        // here parents function will search for the parent tr, where as parent only referes to direct parent of element
        $(this).parents('td').siblings().toggleClass('hide');

    });

});
```

```css
/* class to hide the element */
.hide{ display:none; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with a solution https://jsfiddle.net/sbkw7y3z/

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.sign-reason').change(function() {
    $('.sign-reason').closest('label').toggle();
      $(this).closest('label').show();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td><label><input name="sign-reason" type="checkbox" value="damaged" class="sign-reason"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" class="sign_selector" rel="{cantilever}"><label></label></label></td><td><label><input name="sign-reason" type="checkbox" value="damaged" class="sign-reason"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" class="sign_selector" rel="{950x300}"><label></label></label></td><td><label><input name="sign-reason" type="checkbox" value="damaged" class="sign-reason"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" class="sign_selector" rel="{1300x370}"><label></label></label></td>
    </tr>

    <tr><td><label><input name="sign-reason" type="checkbox" value="damaged" class="sign-reason"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" class="sign_selector" rel="{1000x300fs}"><label></label></label></td><td>&nbsp;</td><td><label><input name="sign-reason" type="checkbox" value="damaged" class="sign-reason"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" class="sign_selector" rel="{1100x300}"><label></label></label></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this easy solution:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.sign-reason').change(function() {
    $('.sign-reason').not(this).closest("td").toggle()
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <label>1
        <input name="sign-reason" type="checkbox" value="damaged" class="sign-reason">
        <img src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/company/img/logos/so/so-icon.svg?v=6e4af45f4d66" class="sign_selector" rel="{cantilever}">
        <label></label>
      </label>
    </td>
    <td>
      <label>2
        <input name="sign-reason" type="checkbox" value="damaged" class="sign-reason">
        <img src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/company/img/logos/so/so-icon.svg?v=6e4af45f4d66g" class="sign_selector" rel="{950x300}">
        <label></label>
      </label>
    </td>
    <td>
      <label>3
        <input name="sign-reason" type="checkbox" value="damaged" class="sign-reason">
        <img src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/company/img/logos/so/so-icon.svg?v=6e4af45f4d66" class="sign_selector" rel="{1300x370}">
        <label></label>
      </label>
    </td>
  </tr>
       
  <tr>
    <td>
      <label>4
        <input name="sign-reason" type="checkbox" value="damaged" class="sign-reason">
        <img src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/company/img/logos/so/so-icon.svg?v=6e4af45f4d66" class="sign_selector" rel="{1000x300fs}">
        <label></label>
      </label>
    </td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>
      <label>5
        <input name="sign-reason" type="checkbox" value="damaged" class="sign-reason">
        <img src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/company/img/logos/so/so-icon.svg?v=6e4af45f4d66" class="sign_selector" rel="{1100x300}">
        <label></label>
      </label>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```